# SharedPreferences in a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, android-fragmentactivity, android-sharedpreferences

I am trying to implement the SharedPreferences in a fragment. I am trying to display the details of the logged in user. However, I am having trouble displaying it on the account Fragment. No problems when displaying SharedPreferences in the MainActivity. I am looking for a solution as to how to cater the code so it will work in a fragment.

MainActivity.java

```
if(!SharedPrefManager.getInstance(this).isLoggedIn()){
            finish();
            startActivity(new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class));
        }
        textviewUsername = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.usernameLabel);
        textviewUsername.setText(SharedPrefManager.getInstance(this).getUsername());
```

In this AccountFragment I am trying to display the account details.

AccountFragment.java

```
public class AccountFragment extends Fragment {
private TextView textViewUsername, textViewEmail, textViewFirstName, textViewLastName;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_account, container, false);

    if(!SharedPrefManager.getInstance(getContext()).isLoggedIn()) {
        startActivity(new Intent(getContext(), LoginActivity.class));
    }

        textViewUsername = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.editTextUsername);
        textViewEmail = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);
        textViewFirstName = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.editTextFirstName);
        textViewLastName = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.editTextLastName);


        textViewUsername.setText(SharedPrefManager.getInstance(getActivity()).getUsername());
        textViewEmail.setText(SharedPrefManager.getInstance(getActivity()).getEmail());
        textViewFirstName.setText(SharedPrefManager.getInstance(getActivity()).getFirstName());
        textViewLastName.setText(SharedPrefManager.getInstance(getActivity()).getLastName());

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an unreachable code in your onCreateView - you are returning View object in first line. You should have something like that:

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_account, container, false);

    if(!SharedPrefManager.getInstance(getContext()).isLoggedIn()) {
        startActivity(new Intent(getContext(), LoginActivity.class));
    }

    textViewUsername = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.editTextUsername);
    textViewEmail = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);
    textViewFirstName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.editTextFirstName);
    textViewLastName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.editTextLastName);

    textViewUsername.setText(SharedPrefManager.getInstance(getActivity()).getUsername());
    textViewEmail.setText(SharedPrefManager.getInstance(getActivity()).getEmail());
    textViewFirstName.setText(SharedPrefManager.getInstance(getActivity()).getFirstName());
    textViewLastName.setText(SharedPrefManager.getInstance(getActivity()).getLastName());

    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well this might work because it works for me. I save it in the fragment with:

```
getActivity().getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,MODE_PRIVATE)
                                .edit()
                                .putString(PREF_EMAIL, email)
                                .putString(PREF_PASSWORD, password)
                                .apply();
```

Then I get them in mainactivity with:

```
SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
    String email = pref.getString(PREF_EMAIL, null);
    String password = pref.getString(PREF_PASSWORD, null);
```

I don't see why it shouldn't work in reverse.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using the default Shared Preferences unless you really need to do otherwise:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPrefs.edit();

editor.putString("key", "value");
editor.apply();
```

Then to retrieve the value:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());
String storedValue = sharedPrefs.getString("key", "defaultValue");
```